# pygame moving blitted text

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am working on this game in pygame and I need to blit some letters on the screen one by one so I created the following code:

```
def suspicious_print(text, font, font_big, t_w, t_h, fill_colour, rect_colour, text_colour):
pygame.font.init()
font = pygame.font.SysFont(font, font_big)
window_disp.fill(fill_colour)
text_print = ""
for letter in text:
    text_print += letter
    render = font.render(text_print, 1, text_colour)
    render_rect = render.get_rect(center = (t_w, t_h))
    pygame.draw.rect(window_disp, rect_colour, render_rect)
    window_disp.blit(render, render_rect)
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(500)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.font.quit()
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
```

The problem is the words are moving to the left side every time the letter appears. How can I prevent the words from moving around and have them stay still?

Comment: Looks like you're effectively "center justifying" the text which moves it each time the rendered text gets longer. You need to "left justify" if you want it to stay still. The line that stands out is `render.get_rect(center = (t_w, t_h))`. Maybe you can just remove that and it will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text is getting centered around `(t_w, t_h)` because of `render_rect = render.get_rect(center = (t_w, t_h))`. Instead of centering you need to left justify the rectangle and always draw it in the same place.

```
render_rect = render.get_rect()
render_rect.x = t_w
render_rect.y = t_h
```

If you want the whole message to be rendered in the center of the screen then you'll need to know 2 things: the size of the final rendered text and the location of the center of the screen. The size of the final box can be found by using the [pygame.font.Font.size](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.size) method on your font. In your case, the following lines should work:

```
font = pygame.font.SysFont(font, font_big)
box_width, box_height = font.size(text)
```

Then you can set the position of `render_rect`:

```
render_rect.x = screen_center_x - box_width / 2
render_rect.y = screen_center_y - box_height / 2
```

I'll leave it up to you to get the center of the screen.

Comment: Thanks alot man really helped me out of this pitty situation.

Comment: @SnailingGoat glad to help out. Mark as correct if it works for you.